# Create-react-app not working through WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, npm-start

I have no idea what is going on here, create react app is not working. After starting installing package, installation aborted in the middle.

I tried to solve this through `npm cache clean --force` and reinstall both WebStorm and node.

Node version: 12.16.1 and WebStorm is 2020.1.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some mixed opinions about Node version- 12.16.1 https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32683 . Try downgrading a bit more, for instance node --version v12.11.1 and see if it works.